# SQL Query - latest inspection for each type of feature and category of inspection

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - `feature` and `inspection`.

The feature table looks like this:

```
 id  | name
-----|-----
1    | tree
2    | flower
...
```

The inspection table looks like this:

```
id | feature_id | category    | date_created
---|------------|-------------|-------------
1  | 1          | inspection  | 10/10/2010
2  | 1          | cleaned     | 10/20/2009
3  | 3          | inspection  | 1/1/2008
4  | 1          | inspection  | 1/1/2005
```

How can I create a query that would give me the most recent inspection for each feature in each category?

```
inspection_id | feature_id | date         | category
--------------|------------|--------------|-----------
1             | 1          | 10/10/2010   | inspection
2             | 1          | 10/20/2009   | cleaned 
3             | 3          | 1/1/2008     | inspection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just choosing the most recent row from a group.  The most common method uses `row_number()`:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by feature_id, category order by date desc) as seqnum
      from inspections i
     ) i
where seqnum = 1;
```